# query many to many table flask sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

I want to check if Client has this retailer in client_retailer table ? so I need function to find if this client has a retailer

```py
client_retailer_table = db.Table('client_retailer',
    db.Column('client_id',  db.ForeignKey('client.id'), primary_key=True),
    db.Column('retailer_id', db.ForeignKey('retailer.id'), primary_key=True)
)

class ClientModel(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'client'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80))
    email = db.Column(db.String(80),unique=True,nullable=False)
    phone = db.Column(db.String(80))
    address = db.Column(db.String(80))
    
    retailers = db.relationship("RetailerModel",secondary=client_retailer_table, backref='retailers')

class RetailerModel(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'retailer'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80))
    email =db.Column(db.String(80),unique=True,nullable=False)
    phone = db.Column(db.String(80))
    address = db.Column(db.String(80))
    
    clients=db.relationship("ClientModel",secondary=client_retailer_table,back_populates="retailers")
```

I try to find if this client has a retailer using this function

```py
def find_by_retailer_id(id):
    return ClientModel.query.filter(ClientModel.retailers.any(retailer_id=id)).first()
```

but I got this error `TypeError: Object of type set is not JSON serializable`

Comment: Nothing in this code produces a `set` or tries to serialise anything to JSON.  Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution with add json method to model

```
    def json(self):
        return {'name': self.name, 'email': self.email,'phone': self.phone,'address': self.address}
```

than

```
# get all retailer
    def get(self):
        return {'retailers': list(map(lambda x: x.json(), ClientModel.find_by_retailer_id()))}
```